# How to programmatically change system time zone

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I'm working on changing system time zone from within WPF application. To do this i'm using unmanaged code that i've found on this site:[changing time zones](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Changing-time-zones). It does change my time zone. However when I click on windows' clock i see a message: "Your current time zone is not recognized. Please select a valid time zone using the link below." I could imagine there is a slight difference somewhere. I've analyzed one time zone - how it's represented before programmatic change and after.

BEFORE:

```
BaseUtcOffset: 4:00:00:00
Daylight Name: "Arabian Daylight Time"
Display Name: "(UTC +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"
Id: "Arabian Daylight Time"
Standard Name: "Arabian Daylight Time"
SupportsDaylightSavingTime: false
```

AFTER:

```
BaseUtcOffset: -4:00:00:00
Daylight Name: ""
Display Name: "Arabian Daylight Time"
Id: "Arabian Daylight Time"
Standard Name: "Arabian Daylight Time"
SupportsDaylightSavingTime: false
```

I found no way to set "Display Name" using TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION. So something that it's called "(UTC +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat" on GUI when changed by user manually using Windows setting, now it's called "Arabian Daylight Time". Perhaps those differences are one of the reasons why i see "Your current time zone..." message. I've read somewhere else that restart helps and this message disappears - unfortunately after restart nothing changes.

Comment: How did you get `-4:00:00:00` (United States Eastern Daylight Time) from `+4:00:00:00`?

Comment: i noticed that of course. it might be a bug in method that creates TimeZoneInformation based on TimeZoneInfo. However it doesn't change anything when it comes to issue i have. Why? because i used once GetTimeZoneInformation method - i've written down all values inside structure and next time i passed EXACTLY the same values. still i had "your current time zone..." message.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I've found my mistake. The problem was that on Windows 7 i was trying to change time zone with:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]   
private static extern bool SetTimeZoneInformation([In] ref TimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);
```

while i should have used:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool SetDynamicTimeZoneInformation([In] ref DynamicTimeZoneInformation lpTimeZoneInformation);
```

Using DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION solved most of the problems regarding my current task.